# Docker daemon failed to create task for container

Tags: docker, ubuntu, huggingface, alpaca

I'm new to both Docker and machine learning. I'm trying to run image of [alpaca_lora](https://github.com/tloen/alpaca-lora) project. I don't know what exactly this problem means. I have Ubuntu 20, I installed Docker Desktop then `docker-ce` with `apt` to have docker deamon. Hello-World docker image work fine.

```bash
docker run --gpus=all --shm-size 64g -p 7860:7860 -v ${HOME}/.cache:/root/.cache --rm alpaca-lora generate.py \
    --load_8bit \
    --base_model '/var/llama/models/llama-7b-hf/' \
    --lora_weights '/var/llama/generations/Demo_Video_ExpansIA_original'
```

Output :

```
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: error during container init: error running hook #0: error running hook: exit status 1, stdout: , stderr: Auto-detected mode as 'legacy'
nvidia-container-cli: initialization error: load library failed: libnvidia-ml.so.1: cannot open shared object file: no such file or directory: unknown.
```